# Bash Programming how to call "$i+1"

Tags: linux, string, bash, terminal, increment

I am writing a script that will allow me to change a char in a string from "#" to something else, if I call an argument in terminal.

eg if I write

```
 ./myprogram testText.txt -r a
```

the -r argument will remove all "#" from testTxt.txt and replace them with "a"

My problem is I do not know how to write "If -r is $x, $x+1 is the char I want for replacement"

This is purely a syntax problem, I'm a bash noob :P. Here is the part of code I'm trying to work with.

```
 for i in $*
 do
     if [[ $i = "-r" ]]
     then
          $customHashChoice=$((i+1))
             # ^^^^^ Problematic Line ^^^^
        fi
 done
```

Comment: Are familiar with `sed` ?...look http://www.grymoire.com/unix/sed.html

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
customHashChoice=($(getopt "r:" "$@" 2>/dev/null))
if [ "${customHashChoice[0]}" == "-r" ]; then
    customHashChoice="${customHashChoice[1]}"
else
    echo "-r option is missing. Aborting..."
    exit 1
fi
```

Syntax: `getopt optstring parameters`

From manual: `getopt` is used to break up (parse) options in command lines for easy parsing by shell procedures, and to check for legal options.  It uses the GNU getopt(3) routines to do this.

Here, optstring is `r:`. It means, that the script accepts an option `-r` & the option takes an argument (implied by `:`).

The output of `getopt "r:" "$@"` is as below:

```
-r <argument to -r option> -- <unmatched parameters>
```

e.g. for command-line arguments,

```
 ./myprogram testText.txt -r a
```

`getopt "r:" "$@"`  returns

```
 -r a -- testText.txt
```

This output is stored in array & the second element of array is used, if the first element is equal to `-r`.

Comment: You should give some explanation of your answer, not just a few lines of code.

Comment: @LeeDuhem: Apologies... Fixed. Thanks.

Comment: Now it is much better :-)

Answer (score 0):

```
i=1
while [ "$i" -le $# ]
do
     if [[ ${!i} = "-r" ]]
     then
         i=$(($i + 1))
         customHashChoice=${!i}
         i=$(($i + 1))
         continue
     fi
     # do something useful
     i=$(($i + 1))
 done
```

The command line arguments are numbered 1 through `$#`.  The above loops through each of them.  If first checks if the current argument is `-r` and, if so, sets `customHashChoice`.

In the above, `i` contains the argument number.  So, `$i` gives the value of `i`.  To access the i'th command line argument, one uses `${!i}`.

#### A more standard approach

The standard way to process command line arguments in shell scripts is `getopts`.  It can handle many options.  Here is sample code that that takes an option `-r` and requires it to have an argument, which is assigned to the shell variable `char`:

```
while getopts r: arg ; do case $arg in
    r)  char="$OPTARG" ;;
    :)  echo "${0##*/}: Must supply an argument to $OPTARG." ; exit 1 ;;
    \?) echo "Invalid option" ; exit 1 ;;
    esac
    done
shift $(($OPTIND - 1))

echo "I will replace @ with $char in file $1"
```

For `getopts` to work, the options have to come first.  So, your command line would becomes:

```
./myprogram -r a testText.txt
```

If this is not acceptable, you can roll your own custom option processor.  In the long run, there is some advantage, however, to standardizing on the usual approach.

Comment: What about `while [ "$*" != "" ]; do`?

Comment: Thanks for your help John, unfortunately the command has to be called before or after (University assignment, anal teacher etc etc) also I am a complete noob and your code looks very impressive and scary. There must be an easier way right? :)

and @txtechhelp, unfortunately that won't do either because I have 3 other arguments to possibly write after :c

Answer (score 0):

You could do something like the following:

```
#!/bin/bash
val=
xval=
fname=$1
while [ "$*" != "" ]; do
    case $1 in
        "-r") val="${2}"; shift ;;
        "-x") xval="${2}"; shift ;;
    esac
    shift
done

echo ${fname} ${val} ${xval}
```

Then when you pass the command like so

```
./myprogram testText.txt -r a
```

`fname` will be `testText.txt`, and the arguments will be parsed (where the `-r` will pick up `a`); for any other values you might want to parse, you'll need variable names to assign and test against. The output would be:

```
testText.txt a
```

Hope that helps

Comment: Hey thanks for your input, this helps slightly but the problem is that -r might be $1 or $2 ... or $x, because I have more than one argument. 

My question is who do I make your ' val="${2}" ' into ' val="${current $ + 1}"'

Comment: That's what the `${2}` does; in bash, the variables numbers are per 'block', so in the `while` block, the `${2}` is saying `{current + 1}`, you then `shift` the `current` off so that `${2}` is now `${1}`. In my example, if you said `val=${1}` then did `echo ${val}` it would print `-r`. Does that make sense?

Comment: The shell allows supplying empty arguments to a script.  This may not be important here but, to handle such a case, one might want to replace `[ "$*" != "" ]` in the `while` statement with `[ $# -gt 0 ]`.

Comment: @John1024, good note; in this instance though, if the arguments passed are empty then `[ "$*" != "" ]` won't evaluate and the loop not done; in this case too if one did an empty argument (like `-r ""` for example) then it's still set, its just 'empty'